# How can I remove error message after inserting valid value in field and selecting another field?

Tags: ajax, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm validating a Sign Up form where I'm displaying error message on the same page. When I'm entering the field value as per requirement and pressing SIGN UP button error message is going off but when I'm trying to insert another field that error message is not going off i.e it's still on the same page. Calling ajax for some functions also.
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: [Sample cum exact code here:]

jsfiddle.net/6uah5wze/2/

Comment: Why not to use HTML "required" attribute?

Comment: That does not solve my problem

Comment: To remove an existing error message you would need to re-validate your form when one of the fields loses focus, using the `onblur` event.